# Page restrictions with normal user and admin

Tags: php, html

Well, on my small site, which I use for practice I created pages where I saved my data from tables from the database, also, I have normal users and admin. I created admin through my sql and I can create a normal user through a registration form on the page. What I want to do is, As I said I have a page where I saved my data from tables, I want to make so user cant see that page while admin can see that page. I just want to make those restrictions. However, I don't know how to start with that in code, I will post here the code that I think you will need for helping me, so, If you need something more, I'm here!

login.php: `

```
    <?php include('functions.php') ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Prijavi se</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="header">
    <h2>Prijavi se</h2>
</div>

<form method="post" action="login.php">

    <?php echo display_error(); ?>

    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Korisnicko ime</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" >
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Lozinka</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="login_btn">Prijavi se</button>
    </div>
    <p>
        Jos uvek nemate nalog? <a href="register.php">Registruj se</a>
    </p>
</form>
```

`

functions.php: `

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'it210projekat');


$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors   = array(); 


if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])) {
    register();
}


if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
    login();
}

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    header("location: ../login.php");
}


function register(){
    global $db, $errors;


    $username    =  e($_POST['username']);
    $email       =  e($_POST['email']);
    $password_1  =  e($_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2  =  e($_POST['password_2']);


    if (empty($username)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Unesite ime"); 
    }
    if (empty($email)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Unesite email"); 
    }
    if (empty($password_1)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Unesite lozinku"); 
    }
    if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "Lozinke se ne poklapaju");
    }


    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);

        if (isset($_POST['user_type'])) {
            $user_type = e($_POST['user_type']);
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, user_type, password) 
                      VALUES('$username', '$email', '$user_type', '$password')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $_SESSION['success']  = "Uspesno ste napravili nalog!!";
            header('location: login.php');
        }else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, user_type, password) 
                      VALUES('$username', '$email', 'user', '$password')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);


            $logged_in_user_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);

            $_SESSION['user'] = getUserById($logged_in_user_id); 
            $_SESSION['success']  = "Uspesno ste se prijavili";
            header('location: login.php');              
        }

    }

}


function getUserById($id){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" . $id;
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $user;
}


function login(){
    global $db, $username, $errors;


    $username = e($_POST['username']);
    $password = e($_POST['password']);


    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { 

            $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
            if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {

                $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                $_SESSION['success']  = "Uspesno ste se prijavili";
                header('location: pocetna.php');          
            }else{
                $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                $_SESSION['success']  = "Uspesno ste se prijavili";

                header('location: pocetna.php');
            }
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Pogresno korisnicko ime ili lozinka");
        }
    }
}

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function isAdmin()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'admin' ) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}


function e($val){
    global $db;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($val));
}

function display_error() {
    global $errors;

    if (count($errors) > 0){
        echo '<div class="error">';
            foreach ($errors as $error){
                echo $error .'<br>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

?>`

I have this on top of page where I want to make restrict for normal users:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
        <div class="error success" >
            <h3>
                <?php 
                    echo $_SESSION['success']; 
                    unset($_SESSION['success']);
                ?>
            </h3>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>


    <div class="profile_info">
        <div>
            <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) : ?>
                <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['user']['username']; ?></strong>
            <?php endif ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can you tell if a user is an admin or not in your database?

Comment: I created user in databse which is admin, `user_type == admin`

Comment: So you have a users table and an admin table? Or do you just have a column in your users table that says `user_type`?

Comment: Before displaying this `private` page you should check if current user is admin. And if so you need nothing to do but if not you must redirect current user elswhere

Comment: Yeah, I have column `user_type`. I made everything good about that, but I dont know how to create page restriciton, so normal user cant see my page where I create code that show all data from tables, while admin can see it

Comment: Okay. Could you add your PHP login code to your question? I need to see how/if you are setting any variables containing the users data.

Comment: Users have to log in, right?  So when they log in, you fetch the row for that user.  Then you check the value of `user_type`.  If not "admin", redirect back to the login or show some message about invalid permissions.

Comment: I updated my answer with login.php and function.php. Yeah, user have to log in. As I said, user can view pages like contact or start page, but cant see page where I storage data from tables, I want to make it so just admin can see that pages where I storage my data from tables

Comment: @MarcusWilliams Several issues with code. 1) [NEVER use md5() for passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138363/why-is-md5-considered-a-vulnerable-algorithm), it's just as bad as plaintext. 2) Your mysql queries are at risk of SQL Injection attacks, you should convert these to [parameterized queries](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection).

Comment: @MarcusWilliams You seem to have an `isAdmin()` function already.  Are you _calling_ that function on the pages that you would like to restrict?  If so, in what way is the result of that not what you want?  If you are _not_ calling that function, you should be.

Comment: Yeah, i have that function but I dont know how to call it on page that I would like to be restrict.

I put function on my page that I would like to be restrict but doesnt work.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton is this good for sql prevention `$korIme = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["korIme"]);`

Comment: @MarcusWilliams Some people would say that yes, `mysqli_real_escape_string` is enough, but I disagree with these people and so does  a large portion of the PHP community. It seems like most people are in agreement that Prepared Statements and Parameterized Queries are the way to go (And they are actually super easy too!). If you want to make it even easier on yourself, I suggest using a wrapper class. The one I wrote, called [GrumpyPDO](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO) is extremely easy to use.

Comment: So how I can fix `$korIme = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["korIme"]);` with PDO? Can you give me one little example just for that?

Comment: @MarcusWilliams Writing an example for that in a comment would not be easily understood. It also depends on if you want to use a wrapper or not. If you want to use GrumpyPDO, just [look at the documentation](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO), it has plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

In your functions file, you are setting `$_SESSION['user']` to the data from the database row for the user; this means you just have to check if `$_SESSION['user']['user_type']` is admin or not.

So, it's simple, on the page you only want admins to see (at the top, below your `functions.php` call), do this:

```
if($_SESSION['user']['user_type'] != 'Admin') {
    //could redirect page here
    die('This page is not available to non-administrators.');
}
```

I noticed a couple of other issues in your login/register code.

- 1) [NEVER use md5()](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138363/why-is-md5-considered-a-vulnerable-algorithm) for passwords, it's considered just as bad as plaintext. Instead, use [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) PHP functions.
- 2) Your mysql queries are at risk of SQL Injection attacks, you should convert these to [parameterized queries](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195816/discussion-on-answer-by-grumpycrouton-page-restrictions-with-normal-user-and-adm). If you are still having related issues, please edit the question with additional information. If it is a separate issue, please ask a new question.